# Mean calculation within bins

Tags: python, numpy, mean, bins

I am trying to calculate mean within each bin.
Everything works okay, but I get 'nan' mean value in the first bin. I suppose it is not correct. Can you help me to find a mistake?

Here is my code:

```
data = np.array([-90,-1,2,3,5,6,8,10,121])

bin_s = np.array([-np.inf, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, +np.inf])

dig = np.digitize(data, bin_s)
sol = np.bincount(dig, data) / np.bincount(dig)
sol
```

[Code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntph1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's `bincount` returns the populations of individual bins. However, if some bins are empty, the corresponding value will be zero, thus the division by `np.bincount(dig)` will fail. A quick fix would be

```
 sol = np.bincount(dig, data) / np.array([max(1, v) for v in np.bincount(dig)])
```

i.e., to divide by 1 instead of 0 for such bins since in this case we know that the bin is empty and thus the corresponding value in `np.bincount(dig, data)` is also zero (however, this would depend on how you want to interpret the mean of an empty bin). This will give:

```
[  0.  -45.5   2.    3.    5.5   8.   65.5]
```

The first element here is not phony, but it corresponds to the zero bin index which would aggregate data smaller than `min(bin_s)`. However, since this number is in your case `-np.inf`, there are no such data. But it might happen that even some intermediary bins turn out to be empty. For example if you take as the input data:

```
data = np.array([-90,-1,2,3,10,121])
```

Then `np.bincount` returns `[0 2 1 1 0 0 2]`, so one needs to handle the other zeros as well, not only disregard the first element...

Also, you might consider [binned_statistic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) provided by scipy which does this directly:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic as bstat

data = np.array([-90,-1,2,3,5,6,8,10,121])

stat = bstat(data, data, statistic = 'mean', bins = [-np.inf, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, +np.inf])
print(stat[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first bin is phony, disregard it:

```
np.bincount(dig, data)[1:] / np.bincount(dig)[1:]
#array([-45.5,   2. ,   3. ,   5.5,   8. ,  65.5])
```